# Can I through click the button of first child to show the second child in same MDI window?

Tags: c#

The first child was called when the MDI window loaded.
The first child have a button that I hope it can call the second child in MDI windows.
Can I make it true?

Comment: Make them both the same MDIParent.

Comment: @LarsTech How to find MDIParent?
In first child I just code "firstChild.MDIParent = this"
But it not work in button on first child.

Comment: We need to see your code to help you.  Wouldn't it be `secondChild.MDIParent = this.MDIParent;`?

Comment: @LarsTech 
I find the answer.
`secondChild.MdiParent = this.MdiParent as MDIwindows;`

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can...use the [MdiParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent?view=netcore-3.1) property:

```
// ... from one MdiChild ...
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.MdiParent = this.MdiParent(); // make the new form have the same MdiParent as the current one
f2.Show();
```

Comment: Of course it works...I've used it many times.  Be a little more descriptive in how it does not work and we can help you fix your error.